# graphicsmagick transparent is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphicsmagick

I am using graphicsmagick npm:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm
```

I am trying to write a code like the following. 
I am trying to make this work with stream ... 
myimg.png is an image with white background.
I want to change the white background to transparent as stated in the npm docs using -transparent.

```
const gm = require('gm');
const fs = require('fs');

// ....

function makeTransparent(){
     const readStream = fs.createStream("myimg.png");
     gm(readStream)
          .transparent("#FFFFFF")
          .stream(function, err, stdout, stderr) {
              const writeStream  = fs.createWriteStream("result.png");
              stdout.pipe(writeStream);
          });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of typos, you need to require your packages as well:

```
var fs = require('fs')
    , gm = require('gm');
const readStream = fs.createReadStream("myimg.jpg");
gm(readStream)
    .transparent("#FFFFFF")
    .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        const writeSTream = fs.createWriteStream("result.png");
        stdout.pipe(writeSTream);
    });
```

Comment: I already did all the requires,and what typos are you talking here?

Comment: @user12822357, you had typos in writeSTream and the function itself

Comment: well, my bad about the typos here, but I still have no idea what is causing the problem. thanks anyway.

Comment: Nvm. i was just being an idiot. There was a bunch of other unrelated problems elsewhere that caused this.